# Powershell encoding can not change with shell_exec, but it can change from console or ps1 file, Why?

Tags: php, powershell, encoding, utf-8

I have **powershell version 5.1**. I want to get some reports from powershell with **shell_exec** in php file and **show on a web page**. Because the resports may contain non english words I want to change the encoding of powershell to UTF8 to support other languages. I use this code in my powershell script (.ps1 file) and the encoding changed truly:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

But I want to run this script from my php file with **shell_exec**. When I run this command in my php file:

```
shell_exec($PowershellPath . '[Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding');
```

and I get the **[Console]::OutputEncoding** in the web page I see the encoding not changed but when I get the [Console]::OutputEncoding in the powershell console I see the encoding change is true and is utf8.

*I think the problem is related to sth like a permission to make change from an external source or the [console] just change the console encodng*

Can anyone help me to change the encoding of powershell with shell_exec ?

Comment: Why should one Powershell process affect a completely different one?

Comment: You know I want to develope a web application that is not in english and I want to change the the encoding to **UTF8**  to support english and other languages. This code change the encoding truely: `[Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object -typename System.Text.UTF8Encoding` but when it is in ps1 file. I want to run it with shell_exec and when I try I saw no error but the encoding not change. Somewhere I read this command change the encoding **locally**. I want to find a way to change the encoding from my php file with **shell_exec**